# Tableau FIXED function on Quicksight

Tags: tableau-api, dashboard, amazon-quicksight, tableau-desktop

im trying to migrate a dashboard from Tableau to Quicksight but im finding difficulties on transforming the calculated field.

```
sum([actuals_for_wape]*
 {FIXED [sort_center], [reporting_date], [ship_method_group]: 
    abs(sum([actuals_for_wape])-sum([lp_forecast_unbuffered]))/sum([actuals_for_wape])
})
/ sum([actuals_for_wape])
```

this is the calculation formula on tableau, i have to do something similar on QS

i tried this

```
(sum({actuals_for_wape})*(abs(sumOver({actuals_for_wape},[{sort_center},{reporting_date},{ship_method_group}])-sumOver({lp_forecast_unbuffered},[{sort_center},{reporting_date},{ship_method_group}]))/sumOver({actuals_for_wape},[{sort_center},{reporting_date},{ship_method_group}])))/sum({actuals_for_wape})
```

But its not working!

Answer (score 0):

I don't have Tableau and the right dataset to try but wondering if of of these expressions work and returns the same result:

Option 1:
(sum({actuals_for_wape}, [])*(abs(sumOver({actuals_for_wape},[{sort_center},{reporting_date},{ship_method_group}])-sumOver({lp_forecast_unbuffered},[{sort_center},{reporting_date},{ship_method_group}]))/sumOver({actuals_for_wape},[{sort_center},{reporting_date},{ship_method_group}])))/sum({actuals_for_wape}, [])

Option 2:
(sumOver({actuals_for_wape}, [])*(abs(sumOver({actuals_for_wape},[{sort_center},{reporting_date},{ship_method_group}])-sumOver({lp_forecast_unbuffered},[{sort_center},{reporting_date},{ship_method_group}]))/sumOver({actuals_for_wape},[{sort_center},{reporting_date},{ship_method_group}])))/sumOver({actuals_for_wape}, [])

I'm expecting Tableau LOD expressions like {FIXED [Dim1], [Dim2]: sum([Measure1])} to be rewritten in QuickSight as sum({Measure1}, [{Dim1}, {Dim2}]). I'm not sure about Tableau's experience when you combine LOD expressions and simple aggregations in the same statement, what level of details does it use for simple aggregations. The options I listed above assume that those are computed at global level.

Hopefully my guidance helps you find the solution.
Please post the working expression here if you find it. I'm curious myself.